# How do I get VirtualBox to use my Windows 7 host machine as a gateway?

Tags: network-share, virtualbox, gateway, internet

I can't seem to find the answer to this.  I have a Windows 7 (64bit) machine that is a company laptop.  Company policy is very strict about adding machines to the network.  I need to run a Linux server to do some Rails development.

Anyway, what I would like to do is have the `Ubuntu 11` guest use my laptop as it's internet gateway.  So that `corp` only sees my one allowed IP address.

How can I do this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I don't know why this was closed and down-voted.  I have explicit permission from the IT network manager to use VirtualBox.  I am just not allowed to have an **additional** IP from the network router because they are scarce with the amount of equipment we have.

In fact, here is the exact email I sent to him:

```
So I have this new Windows laptop.  I’m connecting to the wireless just fine.  
I would like to run this program called VirtualBox which is an open source
virtual environment similar to VMWare.  On this, I would like to run a Linux server.
Well, all’s working but then I noticed my Linux server got its own IP address 
from the wireless router.  I assumed it would share my Windows IP since Windows
is my host.

What is the official position on this?  I can configure the VirtualBox to share
my Windows IP so that as far as you are concerned, I have one IP on the network.
I imagine this is the way to go?

Thanks.
```

Here was his response:

```
It needs to use the IP of your laptop.
<name withheld>, MCSE:Security, JNCIS-SEC
I.T. Network Operations Manager
```

Comment: You should contact your systems administrator and have them configure this for you.

Comment: We are the System Administrators who *enforce company policy*, not help people break it.

Comment: "Question and Answer Site", think you guys a preaching to the wrong crowd.

Comment: Guys, I have permission from the networking department.  I just can't have another IP.  They know exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @cbmeeks In that case you still don't meet the guidelines laid out in the [faq]: `"Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity."` You would probably get a much better response asking on [SU].

Comment: Fine, makes sense.  But the following are links here on SF for VirtualBox questions that have **NOTHING** to do with networking (which mine did)  http://bit.ly/t158OV    http://bit.ly/vNOm4Z   http://bit.ly/tI8laF   And here are VirtualBox question here on SF that are networking related (like mine) that have been **allowed**:  http://bit.ly/ryhAdB   http://bit.ly/rCswpg   http://bit.ly/vVKUaZI guess FAQ's and logic only apply to moderators' moods

Comment: @cbmeeks A bunch of those are from 2009, right after the site launched and the rules were getting sorted out. [This query](http://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualbox%5D+closed%3A1) will show you all of the ones that were closed. Also, what you can't see are the *dozens* that have been deleted after they've been closed. Trust me when I say that the ones that you linked to are the exception and not the rule. If you have any question, you should open a question on [meta].

Comment: Also, you seem to miss the point of my last comment. **Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals.** Judging by your question and comments it seems that you are neither. I'm sorry if you feel that this is an arbitrary distinction, but it's not.

Comment: @MDMarra, I've got to agree with the OP, he might not be a Systems Admin, but I believe the content of the question is perfectly legitimate for this site. If he'd have stated he was a sys admin, would this question have been closed? What's more important, the content of the question, or the person asking it? In fact, the FAQ for SU conflicts with your reasoning, as it says that SU is **not** for "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks", which this question clearly is.

Answer (score 1):

You use NAT mode and your guest will be a transparent device on the network using your host (Win 7) as a gateway. Remember to use DHCP for your guest. (This is optional of course)

Comment: Thanks for assuming I needed an answer to a question instead of assuming I am a crook trying to deceive the company I work for.  I'm allowed to do anything I want to my company laptop.  I just can't have all the IP's I want.  I will try your solution.  I did before but couldn't get INTO the guest for some reason.  So I will try again.  thanks.

Comment: The thing about NAT is that the guest and host have their own separate subnet they run on. Once you have obtained an IP on your guest, find out what that IP is, and you should be able to access it from the host. You may need to setup a separate "Virtual Only" network for accessing the guest from the host, while leaving NAT on for internet traffic. Good luck!

Comment: OK, I got that piece to work.  I now have a 10.x.x.x address on my guest and my host has the corp 172.x.x.x address.  But I can't SSH into my guest?  Any clues?  Thanks!

Comment: SSH service is running on the guest? Can you ping the 10.x.x.x address of your guest from the host?

Comment: Nope.  Can't ping it at all.  Strange.